# Regular expression in python to add a dot after a single letter in a name

Tags: python, regex

How can i use Regular expression in python to add a dot and a space after a single letter in a name, but only if it as a single letter in the beginning, per example:

```
A G Mark
AG Mark
A.G. Mark
```

to this

```
A. G. Mark
```

i have tried this but not working in some cases:

```
import re

line = "A G Mark"
b = re.sub(r' ', r'. ', line)
print (b)
a = re.sub(r'(?<=[.])(?=[^\s])', r' ', line)
print (a)
```

Is it possible to use one case(a) or another(b)?

per example if
`A.G. Mark` use "a"
else
`A G Mark` use "b"
else
`AG Mark` use "c"

Comment: The above code seems to work. Can you be more clear on teh problem?

Comment: Per example if line = "A G Mark" if i put the a and the b it stays the same: A. G. Mark
A G Mark, a and b work in each case but not for all.

Comment: But you said *"but only if it as a single letter in the beginning"*. Do you expect `AG Mark` and `A.G. Mark` to also become `A. G. Mark`?

Comment: AG Mark is an Very rare case, i only included to see if it is possible, if not just A G Mark or A.G. Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all your case, you could try:

```
(?<=[A-Z])\.?\s?(?![a-z])
```

And replace with `.`

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fSwudc/1).

- `(?<=[A-Z])` - Positive lookbehind to assert position after capital alpha.
- `\.?\s?` - Both optional dot and space character.
- `(?![a-z])` - Negative lookahead to prevent being followed by lowercase alpha.

Answer (score 1):

So the distinction of a full name is *"Capital letter followed by lower-case letters"*.

Therefore we want to replace a capital letter, followed by a possible dot, not followed by a lower-case letter and followed by any number of spaces.

This translates to the following substitution:

```
re.sub(r'([A-Z])\.?(?![a-z])\s*', r'\g<1>. ', line)
```

#### Explanation:

**pattern**:

- `([A-Z])` - Capture group of a single capital letter
- `\.?` - matches the character `.` literally. `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- `(?![a-z])` - Negative Lookahead. Assert that the following character doesn't match a single lower-case letter.
- `\s*` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`). `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

**replacement**:

- `\g<1>` - grab the first capture group (the capital letter).
- `.`  - add a dot and a space.

Remember that in the pattern we already match any amount of spaces, so adding the space here will not result in excessive spaces

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V89Tkv/2)

**Code demo**:

```py
import re

lines = """A G Mark
AG Mark
A.G. Mark"""
for line in lines.splitlines():
    print(re.sub(r'([A-Z])\.?(?![a-z])\s*', r'\g<1>. ', line))
```

Which gives:

```
A. G. Mark
A. G. Mark
A. G. Mark
```

Comment: Thank you Tomerikoo, it works also but JvdV was first.

Comment: @ Tomerikoo thank you for tell me that, i am new, but both was helpful, thank you for your time, aim sure it will be helpful for all the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy and paste it in (find and replace) boxs

Find:  `(\w)(\s\w)(\s\w+)`

Replace:  `$1.$2.$3`